# PHP button to change href link on SUBMIT

Tags: php, variables, submit, href

I'm very extremely new to PHP and someone asked me to edit their web page and I took the gig, being semi-well versed in HTML. (I'm an artist you see) gasp...

My problem? Client wants an ON/OFF switch on their admin panel which will display either of two pages on the front end. My guess is a script that'll change the href on the parent page to something specific. I have no idea how to do this. Please help.

What I lack in code ability I more than make up for in my awesome artistic skill so I'll owe you a UI or two ;)

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Very difficult to guess how to approach this problem not knowing how your client's script works.

Comment: We're not here to do your job for you... Sorry.

Comment: Could you explain the nature of the differences in the two pages? Does the client wish to display a different appearance based on the switch, different functionality, or both (essentially an entirely different page)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want a variable in the database that represents the value of the ON/OFF switch. The values can be 1 or 0 or whatever you would like. I would have a single php page, call it `page_redirect.php` that simply has a conditional that tests the flag in the database. it should looks something like this:

```
<?php
$flag = //value from database
if ($flag == 0)
{
  header("Location: url of first page");
}
else
{
  header("Location: url of second page");
}
exit;
?>
```

This way you won't have to change the code in a million different places if the client ever wants to add or change pages.

Comment: Thank you so much @scoobah36 and @Tyler! You've helped me exceedingly well! I know now that my problem was quite open ended, if not downright vague and I appreciate the time everyone took to school me, I really do! If you need a UI or a tour of Zimbabwe I'm your guy. I know it's very n00bish to keep thanking you like this but I'm grateful. I hope you all have very pleasant days.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would create to jpeg's one red, and other white.. or whatever, then create session based upon each SUBMIT, or you could say.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_SESSION['on']) && !empty($_SESSION['on'])) {
echo "<img src='red.jpg' /> ";
}else {
echo "<img src='yellow.jpg' />";
} ?>
```

The above code guaratees you, that if session "on" is set, it will change to red, otherwise, it will always be yellow color.

Now, with the button, how to turn things on and off

I suppose to active the session, you could do something like this below.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['on'])) {
$_SESSION['on'] = true;
}else {
$_SESSION['on'] = false;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not the most simple of tasks and you may end up having to admit to your friend/client that you are not able to do it.  I can't just write the code for you because it would be implemented differently depending on the existing source - but if you are willing to spend some time with the PHP manual and wish to learn I can point you in the right direction.

The button on the admin page needs to save a value on the web server telling the end-user content which content to display (page 1 or page 2 in your case).  The most natural way of doing this is storing a value in a database, usually MySQL, using php.  This will require you to spend some time learning the basic use of MySQL however and your clients webserver will need MySQL support and an active database you can connect to.

Another way would be to store the information in a file on the server.  In PHP you would use the file commands to write the data.  There are examples on the php website, start here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

Look at fopen, fwrite, fread and fclose.  They are the commands you will need if you choose that method.

However, when you have written your data the page that the end user sees will have to load it (either using a database query or fopen, fread and fclose) and then can act on the value you have stored in the file.  A simple way to change which page is seen would be to store the two seperate pages as php files, have a third php page that the client actually sees and use the "include" function from php to load the correct file depending on the value of the data you loaded. ie something like:

```
if ($page_type == 0)
{
    include "page_1.php";
}
else
{
    include "page_2.php";
}
```

At least that is the simplest way I can think of off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

There are alot of ways, From Dynamic JQuery to Static PHP:

**JQUERY:**

First get your buttons:

```
<button id="i1">Show Page 1</button>
<button id="i2">Show Page 2</button>
<div id="loadhere"></div>
```

Now, Use JQuery for loading pages in a specific div.

```
$("#i1").click(function(){
 $("#loadhere").load("page1 link here");
});
$("#i2").click(function(){
 $("#loadhere").load("page2 link here");
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$page = ($selected_page == 0 ? page1:page2)
include("$page.php"); OR header("Location:$page.php");
```